# Call to undefined method DB_CONNECT::query()

Tags: php

I have a problem with my php code, i've read a lot of answer but i didn't find the answer for me.
I have two files: db_connect.php

```
<?php

/**
* A class file to connect to database
*/
class DB_CONNECT {

// constructor
function __construct() {
    // connecting to database
    $this->connect();
}

// destructor
function __destruct() {
    // closing db connection
    $this->close();
}

/**
 * Function to connect with database
 */
function connect() {
    // import database connection variables
    require_once __DIR__ . '/config.php';

    // Connecting to mysql database
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);


    // Selecing database
    $mysqli ->select_db(DB_DATABASE);

    // returing connection cursor
    return $mysqli; 
}



/**
 * Function to close db connection
 */
function close() {
    // closing db connection
    mysql_close();
$mysqli->close();
}

}

?>
```

and get_courses_details.php

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will list all the products
 */



// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// get all products from products table
$result = $db -> query("SELECT * FROM corsi");

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// looping through all results
// products node
$response["corsi"] = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // temp user array
    $corsi = array();
    $corsi ["corso_id"] = $row["corso_id"];
    $corsi ["corso_nome"] = $row["corso_nome"];


    // push single product into final response array
    array_push($response["corsi"], $corsi);
}
// success
$response["success"] = 1;

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
} else {
// no products found
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "No courses found";

// echo no users JSON
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

but when i try to run it display me this message:
Fatal error: Call to undefined method DB_CONNECT::query() in get_courses_details.php on line 19

Do you know how I can do to fix it?

Comment: There is no function `query()` in your `DB_CONNECT` class.

Comment: ...and no connect before query... it will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making a new class object using `$db = new DB_CONNECT();`. Then after you're trying to run `$result = $db -> query("SELECT * FROM corsi");`, but returns a syntax error, since there is no method `query()` in your class object.

What you want to do is make a public property and define this in your `connect()` method, for example:

```
class DB_CONNECT {
    public $sth;

    ...

    public function connect() {
        ...

        $this->sth = $mysqli;
    }
}
```

Now you can use `$db->sth->query()`, as `$db->sth` is your MySQL object now.