# PHP : Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method DB_Connect::storeClient()

Tags: php

What could be wrong with this script?

```
<?php
// json response array
$response = array("error" => FALSE);
if (isset($_POST['amountApplied']) && isset($_POST['mop']) && isset($_POST['term']) && isset($_POST['lastname']) && isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['middlename']) && isset($_POST['birthdate']) && isset($_POST['age']) && isset($_POST['sex']) && isset($_POST['status']) && isset($_POST['marriageDate']) && isset($_POST['noChildren']) && isset($_POST['nationality']) && isset($_POST['acr']) && isset($_POST['address']) && isset($_POST['cityMunicipality']) && isset($_POST['province']) && isset($_POST['telNo']) && isset($_POST['years']) && isset($_POST['offAddress']) && isset($_POST['offCityMunicipality']) && isset($_POST['offProvince']) && isset($_POST['offTelNo']) && isset($_POST['offYears']) && isset($_POST['busAddress']) && isset($_POST['busCityMunicipality']) && isset($_POST['busProvince']) && isset($_POST['busTelNo']) && isset($_POST['busYears']) && isset($_POST['productServiceOffered'])) {
// receiving the post params
$amountApplied = $_POST['amountApplied'];
$mop = $_POST['mop'];
$term = $_POST['term'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$middlename = $_POST['middlename'];
$birthdate = $_POST['birthdate'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$sex = $_POST['sex'];
$status = $_POST['status'];
$marriageDate = $_POST['marriageDate'];
$noChildren = $_POST['noChildren'];
$nationality = $_POST['nationality'];
$acr = $_POST['acr'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$cityMunicipality = $_POST['cityMunicipality'];
$province = $_POST['province'];
$telNo = $_POST['telNo'];
$years = $_POST['years'];
$offAddress = $_POST['offAddress'];
$offCityMunicipality = $_POST['offCityMunicipality'];
$offProvince = $_POST['offProvince'];
$offTelNo = $_POST['offTelNo'];
$offYears = $_POST['offYears'];
$busAddress = $_POST['busAddress'];
$busCityMunicipality = $_POST['busCityMunicipality'];
$busProvince = $_POST['busProvince'];
$busTelNo = $_POST['busTelNo'];
$busYears = $_POST['busYears'];
$productServiceOffered = $_POST['productServiceOffered'];
require 'include/DB_Connect.php';
$db = new DB_Connect();
$result = $db->storeClient($amountApplied, $mop, $term, $lastname, $firstname, $middlename, $birthdate, $age, $sex, $status, $marriageDate, $noChildren, $nationality, $acr, $address, $cityMunicipality, $province, $telNo, $years, $offAddress, $offCityMunicipality, $offProvince, $offTelNo, $offYears, $busAddress, $busCityMunicipality, $busProvince, $busTelNo, $busYears, $productServiceOffered);
    if ($result) {
        // user stored successfully
        $response["error"] = FALSE;
        $response["amountApplied"] = $result["amountApplied"];
        $response["mop"] = $result["mop"];
        $response["term"] = $result["term"];
        $response["lastname"] = $result["lastname"];
        $response["firstname"] = $result["firstname"];
        $response["middlename"] = $result["middlename"];
        $response["birthdate"] = $result["birthdate"];
        $response["age"] = $result["age"];
        $response["sex"] = $result["sex"];
        $response["status"] = $result["status"];
        $response["marriageDate"] = $result["marriageDate"];
        $response["noChildren"] = $result["noChildren"];
        $response["nationality"] = $result["nationality"];
        $response["acr"] = $result["acr"];
        $response["address"] = $result["address"];
        $response["cityMunicipality"] = $result["cityMunicipality"];
        $response["province"] = $result["province"];
        $response["telNo"] = $result["telNo"];
        $response["years"] = $result["years"];
        $response["offAddress"] = $result["offAddress"];
        $response["offCityMunicipality"] = $result["offCityMunicipality"];
        $response["offProvince"] = $result["offProvince"];
        $response["offTelNo"] = $result["offTelNo"];
        $response["offYears"] = $result["offYears"];
        $response["busAddress"] = $result["busAddress"];
        $response["busCityMunicipality"] = $result["busCityMunicipality"];
        $response["busProvince"] = $result["busProvince"];
        $response["busTelNo"] = $result["busTelNo"];
        $response["busYears"] = $result["busYears"];
        $response["productServiceOffered"] = $result["productServiceOffered"];
        $response["error_msg"] = "Application successfully made.";
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // user failed to store
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Required field(s) is missing.";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

**Error:**

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   DB_Connect::storeClient() on line 44.

I can't really distinguish what is wrong with the script. I just got this script in a tutorial and little by little studying it. Any help, tips and assistance will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

and this is the DB_Connect

```
<?php
class DB_Connect {
    private $conn;


// Connecting to database
public function connect() {
    require 'include/Config.php';

    // Connecting to mysql database
    $this->conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

    // return database handler
    return $this->conn;
}
}

?>
```

Comment: Can you please post the code in 'include/DB_Connect.php'

Comment: look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33668770/call-to-undefined-method-db-connectquery

Comment: @GrantC. added the DB_Connect.php

Comment: You need to add more to the DB_Connect class. Also the 'connect()' method needs to be run before anything can be done with the database. You are getting the error doesn't have a storeClient() method. Does the tutorial you are following have any more info on what should be put in DB_Connect?

Answer (score 0):

you only instance the DB_Connect Object, but you never call the connect.

So:

```
...
require 'include/DB_Connect.php';
$db = new DB_Connect();
$db->connect();
$result = $db->storeClient ...
```

This should do the trick :)